# How to run a SCORM .zip file URL in Objective C with SCORM interactions

Tags: ios, scorm

How to run a SCORM .zip file URL in Objective C with SCORM interactions.

Please share a Sample code for same or Let me know How can I use this

https://github.com/RusticiSoftware/TinCanObjC

Answer (score 0):

A SCORM zip file itself isn't runnable, generally it has to be imported and a manifest file contained therein (`imsmanifest.xml`) points to an HTML file contained in the package that is loaded (or "launched") into a browser or web view. That HTML file interacts with a JavaScript API which is what is specified by the SCORM runtime environment. The JS API is provided by a SCORM "player", and recording interaction data is one of the APIs exposed and is dependent on the SCORM version of the package.

The linked library, TinCanObjC, is generally unrelated to SCORM and implements the xAPI communication protocol.

Playing SCORM content outside of a mobile browser, potentially offline, is a non-trivial solution, you may want to have a look at https://scorm.com/scorm-solved/scorm-engine/mobileoffline-scorm/

Comment: Thanks for your answer, how that html file interacts with Javascript Api?

Comment: There is a pre-defined search algorithm in the SCORM spec that indicates how the window hierarchy should be traversed and the name of a global object that exposes the JS API. That is all in the RTE specification. There is an overview at https://scorm.com/scorm-explained/technical-scorm/run-time/